# How should I put the BroadcastReceiver class code in a Service class so that I can register and unregister it inside the service class?

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am making a **Countdown Timer Android app** in which I am starting a **service** named TimerService to keep the timer running even if the app is sent to background. I want to **set an alarm** of the timer duration within the service when the timer is started. And when the alarm is triggered, I want to notify the user with a **Notification**. I am running the timer using a **Handler**.
Currently I have tried to set the alarm in the service in which I am passing counDownDuration to setAlarm(long).And when the alarm is triggered, a toast is showed by the receiver class. But the **problem** is, the alarm is getting triggered at **random time**.(mainly within 3-5 seconds)

Here's my code:

TimerService.java

```
private long countDownDuration = 25000;//25 sec timer   
public void startTimer(){
    mIsTimerRunning = true;
    startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    setAlarm(countdownTimer);
    Log.i(TAG,"Timer Started");
}
private void setAlarm(long countDownDuration){
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerExpiredReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mAlarmManager.setExact(ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, countDownDuration, sender);
    } else {
        mAlarmManager.set(ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, countDownDuration, sender);
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm Set of " + countDownDuration/1000 );
}

private void cancelAlarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerExpiredReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mAlarmManager.cancel(sender);
    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm Cancelled");
}
```

TimerExpiredReceiver.java

```
public class TimerExpiredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // context.mIsTImerRunning = false;
    Toast.makeText(context,"Time's Up!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

**Update 1:**
Figured out the cause of random triggering. Made changes in the TimerService's startTimer() and setAlarm(long).
Here is the updated TimerSerive code:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

protected static final String TAG = "TimerService";
private long startTime, endTime;
private boolean mIsTimerRunning;
private final IBinder mBinder = new TimerBinder();
private static int count = 0;
private long countDownDuration = 25000;//25 sec timer
private long wakeUpTime;
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
private BroadcastReceiver mAlarmReceiver;
public TimerService() {
    count++;
    Log.i(TAG,"TimerService Object No. " + count);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service Created");
    startTime = 0;
    endTime = 0;
    mIsTimerRunning = false;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Service Started");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Service Bound");
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG,"Service Destroyed");
}

public void startTimer(){
    mIsTimerRunning = true;
    startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    wakeUpTime = startTime + countDownDuration;
    setAlarm(wakeUpTime);
    Log.i(TAG,"Timer Started");
}

public void stopTimer(){
    mIsTimerRunning = false;
    endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
    cancelAlarm();
    Log.i(TAG,"Timer Stopped : endtime = " + endTime);
}

public int getElapsedTime(){
    return (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime);
}

public boolean isTimerRunning() {
    return mIsTimerRunning;
}

private void setAlarm(long wakeUpTime){
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerExpiredReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mAlarmManager.setExact(ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, wakeUpTime, sender);
    } else {
        mAlarmManager.set(ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, wakeUpTime, sender);
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm Set of " + wakeUpTime/1000 );
}

private void cancelAlarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerExpiredReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mAlarmManager.cancel(sender);
    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm Cancelled");
}

public class TimerBinder extends Binder {
    TimerService getService() {
        return TimerService.this;
    }
}}
```

**Problem**:
Now seeking a way to put the **TimerExpiredReceiver** code **inside** the Timerservice so that it can be **registered** and **unregistered** inside the service. As well as the **receiver** can **access** the members of TimerService class and can show a **notification** instead of a **toast**. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

start the alarm service just after your counter expires and set the time to 0 so that it will start ringing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, ServiceClass.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 0*1000, pintent);
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have figured out the problem and I have posted the update. Now seeking to solve the remaining problem.